# MahApps.Metro button fontsize is not inherited from metrowindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am beginning to learn WPF and I choose MahApps.Metro for styling as it looked cool. The problem I am facing is that after changing the font of MetroWindow the WindowCommandButton's font is updated accordingly but the font of the buttons is not getting updated. I continue to see tiny texted buttons.

My XAML looks like this as of now

```
<MahApps:MetroWindow
    x:Class="MetroSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MetroSample"

    xmlns:MahApps="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Metro Sample" 
    Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" FontSize="14.667">

<MahApps:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <MahApps:WindowCommands>
        <Button x:Name="btnReqLogs">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_book_list}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Request Logs" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="btnSettings">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_settings}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Settings" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </MahApps:WindowCommands>
</MahApps:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>

<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

    <DockPanel Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Top" LastChildFill="False">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left"
            MahApps:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True" Background="Transparent"
            Content="First Button" Padding="10,0" Width="150" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>

        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left"
            MahApps:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True" Background="Transparent"
            Content="Second Button" Padding="10,0" Width="150" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>

        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            MahApps:ButtonHelper.PreserveTextCase="True" Background="Transparent"
            Content="Logout" Padding="10,0" Width="150" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
    </DockPanel>

    <StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button.FontFamily` doesn't inherit from parent control. [It is defined in the base style :](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml#L334)

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultFont}" />
```

You can override that with the following :

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Lucida Sans Unicode" />
</Style>
```

Or, you can override that globally for every style that also happens to use it via (but, don't do this) :

```
<FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFont">Lucida Sans Unicode</FontFamily>
```

Comment: Thanks Xiaoy312, requirement is that I need to implement an option for end-user where he/she can increase/decrease the font size as per his preference and based on the entered size and family, every control's font should get updated. In this context I think the last option seems more feasible.

My initial approach was to derive all Windows from a base window class and update the font of base class (as I used to do in WinForms). So any advice would be highly appreciated